# Div not contained in cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to position and contain a carousel in a table cell (left of a two cell row). The carousel keeps duplicating itself to the right, but works without the whole table structure correctly. My whole reason for doing this is to align the carousel and a button/image content vertically so that they stay in place when resizing the browser.

Here is the full code:

```js
var someFunction = function() {};

(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    dots: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]
  })
})();



someFunction();
```

```css
.owl-carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 44%;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
}

.owl-prev {
  left: 0.5vh;
}

.owl-next {
  right: 0.5vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.theme.default.min_home_up_6.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

  <table style="width: 100%;"><tr><td width="75%" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><div class="owl-carousel owl-theme"><div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="img1.jpg"></div><div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="img2.jpg"></div></div></td><td width="25%" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Unknown stuff to be centered. </td></tr></table>
```

Any idea

Comment: can you please get us jsfiddle

Comment: I'm not saying you can't do this with a `<table>` but modern web design generally frowns on it.  There are better alternatives for responsive design and good vertical alignment.

Comment: @AshishBalchandani jsfiddle?

Comment: @nurdyguy: How would you do this instead? I am not at all attached to a <table> solution.

Comment: @FatTwin: Flexbox

Comment: [A Guide to Flexbox - CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: @FatTwin Between bootstrap and flexbox you should be able to get this done.  Even if you don't decide to use flexbox here, checkout out the link Erik mentioned, it is fantastic!

Comment: @nurdyguy I will dig into it and report back a bit later today. I am still very much in my baby shoes here, but it's always great to get new, better input on how to do things. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still a bit messy, but this is my solution:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

var someFunction = function(){};

(function() {
    
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    dots: true,
    navText: ["<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"]
})
            })();



someFunction();
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2793/0346/files/owl.theme.default.min_home_up_6.css">


.owl-carousel {
position: relative;
}
.owl-prev,
.owl-next {
position: absolute;
top: 44%;
height: 10vh;
width:10vh;


}
.owl-prev {
left: 0.5vh;
}
.owl-next {
right: 0.5vh;
}

@import "compass/css3";

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */
  
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item_1 {
  width: 67%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;

  
}

.flex-item_2 {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  
  &.first {
    height: 50%; 
    background: silver;
  }
  &.second {
    height: 50%; 
    background: lightgray;
  }
}
```

```html
  <ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item_1">
    
     <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    
<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/Shot_Slider.jpg"></div>
    
<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/Tea_Slider.jpg"></div>

<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/CBD_Slider.jpg"></div>

<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/Bowl_Slider.jpg"></div>

<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/Water_Slider.jpg"></div>

<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/Dry_Goods_Slider.jpg"></div>

<div class="item" style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="/files/1/2793/0346/files/Green_Slider.jpg"></div>
    

</div>
    
  </li>
  <li class="flex-item_2">
    
    <ul>
  <li class="first" style="font-size:50px; background: #FF8566;">Fresh & Juicy</li>
  <li class="second" style="font-size:50px;"><a href="/pages/menu_up">SHOP</a></li>
</ul>
    

    
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks again for all the help, especially the tip with Flexbox!